# Predict the date an item will be sold using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I would like to predict the date a item will be sold using features such as:

```
      Product ID          Price        Days_since_first_post       Last_repost     Type       First_Post_Date         Sold_Date
```

How would machine learning principles be used in such a way to do this task? If so, what is the proper means by which to design such an algorithm? What would be the different steps which would be involved.

More generally, what are the logical steps that should be taken when tackling a machine learning problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine learning problem can be separated into a few modular parts. Of course these are all massive in reach and possibility. However, every problem you encounter should be thought of in this way at first. You can then skip things where you feel necessary.

- Data pre-processing and feature extraction
- The model
- Post-processing

### **Data pre-processing and feature extraction**

This and feature extraction are the two most important parts of a machine learning technique. That's right, NOT THE MODEL. If you have good features then even a very simple model will get amazing results.

Data pre-processing goes from your raw data and remolds it to be better suited to machine learning algorithms. This means pulling out important statistics from your data or converting your data into other formats in order to it being more representative. For example if you are using a technique which is sensitive to range, then you should normalize all your features. If you are using text data you should build word vectors. There are countless ways pre-processing and feature extraction can be implemented.

Then, you want to use feature selection. From all the information you extracted from your data not all of it will be useful. There are machine learning algorithms such as: PCA, LDA, cross-correlation, etc. Which will select the features that are the most representative and ignore the rest.

**In your case**

First, let's consider the data pre-processing. You notice that type might not be an integer value. This may cause problems when using most machine learning algorithms. You will want to bin these different types and map them onto numbers.

Feature selection: besides using the techniques I outlined above, you should also notice that productID is a useless feature. It should for sure NOT be included in your model. It will just confuse the model and sway it.

As a general rule of thumb, the amount of data that is suggested to have for shallow machine learning models is $10 \times \#features$. So you are limited by the size of your dataset. Also, make sure the outputs are quite well distributed. If you have some skew in your dataset, like a lot of examples where the item was sold right away, then the model will learn this tendency. You do not want this.

### The Model

Now that you have your feature-space, which might be entirely different from the original columns you posted, it is time to choose a model. You are trying to estimate the time of sale for an algorithm. Thus, this can be done in two different ways. Either as a classifier problem or as a regression problem.

The classifier problem would separate the different times of sales into distinct bins. For example

- Class 1: [0 - 5] days
- Class 2: [5 - 10] days
- etc...

Of course the more classes you will choose to have then the harder it will be to train the model. That means the resolution of your results is limited by the amount of the data you have available to you.

The other option is to use a regression algorithm. This will learn the tendency of your curve in higher dimensional space and then estimates where along that line a new example would fall. Think of it in 1-dimension. I give you a bunch of heights $x$ and running speeds $y$. The model will learn a function $y(x)$. Then if I give you just a height, you will be able to estimate the running speed of the individual. You will be doing the same thing but with more variables.

There are really a ton of methods that can do this. You can look through some literature reviews on the subject to get a hold of all of them. But, I warn you there is A LOT. I usually start with kernel-Support Vector Regression (k-SVR).

To test your model. Separate your dataset into three parts (training, validating, testing) if you have sufficient data. Otherwise two parts (training, testing) is also fine. Only, train your model on the training set and then evaluate it using the example it has not seen yet which are reserved in the testing set.

### Post-processing

This is the step where you can further model your output $y(x)$. In your case that might not be needed.

Comment: Very well explained, I would like to know how then we can use the validation data ? I've seen this many times but did not understand its difference with the testing one

Comment: It's just more realistic. If you test on your testing set directly, then you shouldn't make any changes to your algorithm because it's kind of cheating. You are likely to overfit in that case. However, if you have a validation set you can test on it, then make changes. When you are satisfied then use the testing set and claim those results as accurate.